# sidekiq_retries_exhausted never firing

Tags: ruby, sidekiq

What might be the reason for `sidekiq_retries_exhausted` not being called? Is there some setting I am missing?

Probably something is overriding `sidekiq_options retry: 1`, and the worker keeps retrying, but what?

```
class SomeWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  sidekiq_options retry: 1

  sidekiq_retries_exhausted do |msg|
    # => never hit this point
    Rails.logger.info "tried two times, failed"
  end

  def perform(_args)
    raise
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that when adding a job via code like this:

```
  Sidekiq::Client.push(
    'class' => 'SomeWorker',
    'args' => [
      foo: "bar",
    ],
  )
```

retries setting in the class declaration `sidekiq_options retry: 1` is omitted for some reason (bug?/ by design?). Instead `'retry' => 1` needs to be explicitly set:

```
  Sidekiq::Client.push(
    'class' => 'SomeWorker',
    'args' => [
      foo: "bar",
    ],
    'retry' => 1
  )
```

Comment: If you use the Class, it will pick up the worker default options. `'class' => SomeWorker`   When you only pass the String, you need to pass any other default options.